# Парсер JPG. Объясните работу кода

Tags: python, парсер, jpeg

Парсер JPG. Брал отсюда: https://github.com/jhnwr/image-downloader/blob/main/imagedownloader.py Его недостатки: парсит картинки только с определенного сайта, с ALT. Не парсит картинки, где URL - урезанный, без HOSTа. Переделал. Заменил

```
    for image in images:
            name = image['alt']
            link = image['src']
```

На то, что мне нужно,чтобы парсить картинки с другого сайта. Получилось вот что:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import os
    import re
    
    def imagedown(url, folder):
        try:
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
        except:
            pass
        os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        images = soup.find_all('img')
        for image in images:
            link = image['src']
            if re.search(r'\bjpg\b', link):
                link2 = link
                # print(link2)
                # for line in link2:
                name = link2.split("/")[-2]
                with open(name.replace(' ', '-').replace('/', '') + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                 im = requests.get(link2)
                 f.write(im.content)
                 print('Writing: ', name)
    
    imagedown('https://www.rogerebert.com/contributors/nick-allen#articles', 'bratislava')
```

Не совсем понятны несколько вещей. Если в  `im = requests.get(link2)`поменять link2 на link - ничего не меняется, картинки так же парсяться. Почему?
Второй вопрос: нужно ли указывать и в этом коде, чтобы сайты не ругались:

```
  

      headers = {
            "Accept": 'accept: ...'
            "User-Agent": "..."
```

И объясните эту часть кода, как она работает:

```
im = requests.get(link)
            f.write(im.content)
            print('Writing: ', name)
```

И не совсем в тему вопрос. Можно ли давать ссылки на свой код в GitHub? А не постить код здесь. Или это не наглядно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `images = soup.find_all('img')` отвечает за поиск всех картинок, во всей области тела Body. Поэтому и работает на других сайтах, т.к. структура всех сайтов одинаковая header,body,footer .
2. Да, и это еще маленькая часть автомат.прохода на сайт .
3. Это что бы видеть что скачало, и красиво принтуем в терминал .

Советую посмотреть и заценить канал, в прошлом он очень помог [ссылка на видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vwoc0n6Isc) .

Comment: Молчанов. Чувак про Азы в парсинге. Находил его курсы ан торрентах. Полезные. Но есть гораздо круче чувак, у которого вообще все четко. Правда мало. Но он крут https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrWWcscvUWaqdQJLQQGO6BA

Comment: Я и про азы скинул))
По делу вещает. Спасибо за новое)

Comment: Буржуин -парсер. ) https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8tgRQ7DOzAbn9L7zDL8mLg Есть чему поучиться